# Why is my laptop louder and warmer while running Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD than Windows 10 on SSD?

Tags: laptop, overheating

I noticed that my laptop is instantly after starting Ubuntu from HDD starting to be loud and warm, although having only Firefox and the terminal open (atm), but I believe the situation is identical without any open apps. 
I think it actually colored my white desk to black a bit twice, from warm plastic?, it did I'm only in partial denial.

It is really noticeable change in sound and heat after using Windows 10 which is running on an SSD.

I think this didn't happen before last few months, but only since 1-2 weeks ago.

I considered taking it to cleaning or buying cooling fan, but at the end I was too lazy/busy/poor for both.

I'm asking for possible cause because I'm kind of worried that some component could die or something? I'm just checking for someone with knowledge to tell me to stop worrying.

I would say this isn't relevant that much but OK, just in case it is I'll list some components (Acer cheap plastic case, i3-5005U, GeForce 940M 2GB, HDD 1000GB,4GB RAM ddr3 + extra added SSD and 8GB RAM)

Comment: @intersect - Those are extremely low temperatures for a low CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

Because SSDs have no moving parts they generate less heat than HDDs, which indicates that the noise and heat is not necessarily caused by a software issue. The only way to find out for sure is to install both OSs in the dual boot on the SSD.

Ubuntu would require 25 GB recommended hard disk space in order to be installed on a separate partition on the SSD. Allocating at least 25 GB of disk space for an Ubuntu partition wouldn't be a problem if the second hard disk was a 256 GB SSD. New installations of Ubuntu 17.04 and later use a swap file instead of a swap partition, so only one partition for Ubuntu is needed.